# Java Date Issue On the Jboss Server

Tags: java, date, jboss

I have a web and mobile application. The application has kind of items that user can add using either the website or mobile app. Both add item forms have date field which is stored in the database in milliseconds.

User select date in mobile app using date picker and the format that is transferred to the server via web service is mm/dd/yyyy (08/03/2011).

When the data is received by the server, I have following code which converts this date into milliseconds.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(df.parse("08/03/2011"));
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
long milliseconds = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

Although the above code works and inserts the data into database but when the website queries the data and show the date it's a month off. So if it's 08/03/2011 inserted by the mobile app, the website shows 07/03/2011. I wonder what's wrong here?

Comment: Is the date put out correctly in the program? try something like System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));

Comment: Yes the whole service and app works fine with the local jboss server

Comment: so then the problem lies somewhere in the database layer. how are storing it in the databse? Does it help when you store it as a Date (c.getTime())

Comment: the data type of the date column is "bigint"

Answer (score 1):

Arent you adding a month to the date in your code:

```
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

Comment: If I am adding the month, it should be 09/03/2011 but it's 07/03/2011

Comment: It just seems suspicious that you're altering your date by a month (why?) and then its out by a month on retrieval, albeit in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

The first month in the Calendar is '0', basically means if you add one month to 08/03/2011 and print it using c.get(Calendar.MONTH) it will show '8'

Comment: The thought was that if there is a one month offset, somewhere in the code is the month-start-from-zero forgotten. However, I think you need to analyze the problem more in detail. Try to watch what sent value is, then what found in database, what is read out before the formatting, what value is after formatting, what is sent back to the client as response.